# how can I applying multiple row data in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am a new bee to python and Pandas, I have a huge data set and insted of applying function row by row I want to apply to a batch of rows and return back the result and associated back to the same corresponding row back

Example:

```
ID  Values
a   2
b   3
c   4
d   5
e   6
f   7

df['squared_values']= df['values'].apply(lambda row: function(row))

def function(x):
   #making call to api and returning values related to x
   return response
```

above one apply function row by row which is time consuming

I need a way to do batch operations on row

```
example:


batch=3


df['squared_values']= df['values'].apply(lambda batch: function(batch))

on first pass values should be 

ID  Values squared_values
a   2        4
b   3        9
c   4        16
d   5
e   6
f   7

on second pass 
ID  Values squared_values
a   2        4
b   3        9
c   4        16
d   5        25
e   6        36
f   7        49
```

Comment: `df['Values'] ** 2`

Comment: If squaring the numbers is your only requirement then you can try @rafaelc comment.

Comment: sorry I have given a sample squaring is not my requirement my example was bad. my function actually make a call to api and then return  values, requesting values one by the  has network latency so I am thinking to send batch of values once and getting  result I have edited my original question

Answer (score 0):

Is this operation really too slow?

`df['squared_values'] = df['Values'] ** 2`

you can always add the iloc to select rows:

`df.iloc['squared_values'].update(df.iloc[0:4]['Values'] ** 2)`

But I can't imagine this being quicker

Comment: sorry my example was bad. my function actually make a call to api and then return  values, requesting values one by the  has network latency so I am thinking to send batch of values once and getting  result I have edited my post.

Comment: Then maybe df.apply is not the way to go, as far as I am aware this is designed to apply a function either row/column-wise to a dataframe. Possibly pass chunks of the dataframe to the api/function (provided the api can handle this) returning the result back to the dataframe?

Comment: Yes API can handle the chunks, correct return result back to dataframe.